# Сортировка объектов по полю с дополнительной логикой

Tags: java, сортировка, list, compare

Есть класс `Word`, у него есть поле `String word`. Создаем список из объектов `List<Word> words`.

Нужно отсортировать объекты по количеству вхождений определенной буквы в поле `String Word word`.

Подскажите, как лучше отсортировать такой список? `Comparable` и `Comparator` здесь не подходят (ну или я не понял как), т.к. буква, по которой нужно сортировать заранее не известна, и нам еще нужно подсчитать ее количество в каждом слове.

```java
public class Word {
    private final String word;

    public Word(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала можно написать метод, который считает количество вхождений буквы в `Word`:

```
/**
* Подсчет количества вхождений буквы в слово
*/
static int countLetter(Word word, char letter) {
     String w = word.word;
     return w.length() - w.replace(letter + "", "").length();
}
```

Затем его можно использовать и в компараторе с методом `sort`:

```
words.sort((Word o1, Word o2) -> {
            int c1 = countLetter(o1, 'a');
            int c2 = countLetter(o2, 'a');
            return Integer.compare(c1, c2);
        });
```

И со стримами, если нужно:

```
List<Word> sortedWords = words.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(w -> countLetter(w, 'a')))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Оба метода могут рассчитывать количество более одного раза для одного слова. Если количество слов будет огромным и возникнут проблемы с производительностью, то может потребоваться предварительно рассчитать количество вхождений для каждого слова (создать для этого отдельный массив/класс/пару значений).

Answer (score 2):

Если для производительности некритично вычисление числа вхождений буквы при каждом сравнении, то нужно просто сделать букву полем компаратора и внутри метода сравнения выполнять подсчёт.

Если нужно сделать более оптимально, то создаём массив пар `ссылка, количество`. Компаратор по-прежнему получает букву в конструкторе, но обращается к уже посчитанному количеству вхождений. А после сортировки проходим по новому массиву и из него присваиваем элементы в оригинальный.

При желании вместо передачи в конструктор можно использовать замыкание.

Answer (score 0):

Добавляем в класс `Word` метод, который считает количество вхождений буквы в слово. Далее сравниваем два числа, полученных из этого метода:

```java
public class Word {
    private final String word;

    public Word(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public int letterCount(char letter) {
        return (int) word.chars().filter(ch -> ch == letter).count();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return word;
    }
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Word> list = Arrays.asList(
            new Word("aabb"), new Word("babbab"),
            new Word("babbab"), new Word("aabb"),
            new Word("baabbaab"), new Word("ba"),
            new Word("ba"), new Word("abbaabba"));

    list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(w -> w.letterCount('b')));

    System.out.println(list);
    // [ba, ba, aabb, aabb, babbab, babbab, baabbaab, abbaabba]
}
```